# ExpressJS change route without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, handlebars.js

Hey I have a website run with **Express.js** and **Handlebars** that has a navbar and sidebar that stays the same for all the pages. When I route it only changes the page container which is `{{{body}}}`.

Is there a way I can just load the content of the routes without the page actually refreshing and reloading the nav and sidebar?

I'm currently using this for routing.

```
router.get('/', checkAuthentication, function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});
```

Any help would be nice as I'm quite new with node.

I want only the container to load not the whole url/page

Answer (score 1):

you can send the data you need to the client using:

```js
res.send(JSON.stringify(Obj);
```

and in the ajax success function you need to:

```js
JSON.parse(dataSentFromServer);
```

and render the data using handlebars in the success function or another function that you call

Comment: Is it this complicated just to change the view without reloading on express?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for considering/looking at the post, i have come to the conclusion to be using **PJAX** to do this.

The tutorial i read, for anyone wondering is : [Pjax Tutorial](https://ntotten.com/2012/04/09/building-super-fast-web-apps-with-pjax/)