# How do I return a partial, not a view, to the front end? Can I return a partial without a page refresh?

Tags: express, express-handlebars

So I'm working in express and using hbs as my view engine. I want to make a fetch call from the front end passing form data to my express server. I then want to send a partial with the data sent from the front end to the front end so only that section of the page is updated. Also I want the page to not refresh so I want it to be asynchronous. Is this possible and, if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same long time ago with ajax/jquery, and It could be exausting, extense etc, I recomend to you use vue, react or angular, to handle your front end.

If you want to continue with this you can see this answer:

[express.js how to update UI without refresh all page using handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772487/express-js-how-to-update-ui-without-refresh-all-page-using-handlebars)