# Refresh data on page without reloading the page in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax

i need to refresh data on page without page reload in nodejs. Below code refresh the page without page reload but .hbs file is not found error coming. How can i resolve it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contenUpdate").load("abc.hbs");
    var refreshId = 
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#contentUpdate").load("abc.hbs");
    }, 1000);
    $.ajaxSetup({cach:false});
})
```

//abc.hbs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RlIU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2fcl.png)

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314067/how-to-create-a-no-refresh-page-using-jquery-express-and-handlebars

Comment: What about Without HBS tho @Valiant is there a way without HBS???